# SQL Server: errors when trying to alter the tables to add a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm creating a database right now, I have successfully created my Tables, columns, PRIMARY keys, made sure the data types are correct.

However right now when I try to do the next step of my database creation (which is defining foriegn key constraint) I can't do it and will get an error like:
"The number of columns in the referencing column list for foreign key 'FK_TWEEDLEDEER_SHIPROSTER' does not match those of the primary key in the referenced table 'SHIP_ROSTER'."

Here is all of my tables. This error is right now between the "TWEEDLEDEER" table and the "SHIP_ROSTER" table where I am trying to create a foreign key which describes the relationship through the "Tweedle_No" column

```
USE MASTER
GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM MASTER ..sysdatabases
                   WHERE NAME = N'SpaceshipRaiders')
DROP DATABASE SpaceshipRaiders;
GO

CREATE DATABASE SpaceshipRaiders;
GO
USE SpaceshipRaiders;
CREATE TABLE TWEEDLEDEER(
Tweedle_No   INT,
FirstName    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastName     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Birth_Date   DATETIME NOT NULL,
Dead_Date    DATETIME NOT NULL, 
Gender       NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Position     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Father       INT NOT NULL,
Mother       INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT tweedledeer_pk PRIMARY KEY (Tweedle_No)
CONSTRAINT FK_TWEEDLEDEER_TWEEDLEDEER1 FOREIGN KEY (Father) REFERENCES TWEEDLEDEER,
CONSTRAINT FK_TWEEDLEDEER_TWEEDLEDEER FOREIGN KEY (Mother) REFERENCES TWEEDLEDEER,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE POSITION(
PositionName    NVARCHAR(50),
Description     TEXT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT position_pk PRIMARY KEY (PositionName)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE SHIP_ROSTER(
ShipRego_No     INT,
Tweedle_No      INT NOT NULL,
CommencementDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
Termination_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
Medal           NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT ship_roster_pk PRIMARY KEY (ShipRego_No, Tweedle_No, CommencementDate)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE SPACESHIP(
ShipRego_No   INT NOT NULL,
ShipName      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LightYearsTravelled   INT NOT NULL,
MaxWarpSpeed  INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT spaceship_fk PRIMARY KEY (ShipRego_No)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE MEDAL(
Medal    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Value    MONEY NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT medal_pk PRIMARY KEY (Medal)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE RAID(
Raid_No      INT NOT NULL,
ShipRego_No  INT NOT NULL,
Planet_No    INT NOT NULL,
Date         DATETIME NOT NULL,
StartTime    DATETIME NOT NULL,
EndTime    DATETIME NOT NULL,
OppositionLevel NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT raid_pk PRIMARY KEY (Raid_No)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE PRISONER(
Prisoner_Id     INT NOT NULL,
FirstName       NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastName        NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
YearOfBirth     INT NOT NULL,
YearOfDeath     INT NOT NULL,
Raid_No         INT NOT NULL,
RansomPaid      MONEY NOT NULL,
Colour          NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT prisoner_pk PRIMARY KEY (Prisoner_Id)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE PLANET(
Planet_No   INT,
Name        NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DayLength   INT NOT NULL,
Atmospher   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Technology  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Star_No     INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT planet_pk PRIMARY KEY (Planet_No)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE STAR(
Star_No   INT,
Name      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SpectralType      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Position      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT star_pk PRIMARY KEY (Star_No)
)
GO
```

And also I was trying to alter the table with this method

```
alter table TWEEDLEDEER 
add constraint FK_TWEEDLEDEER_SHIPROSTER
FOREIGN KEY(Tweedle_No) REFERENCES SHIP_ROSTER
```

Answer (score 1):

Table `SHIP_ROSTER` has 3 columns as primary key and while using it in reference, You are using only one column while it is expecting 3 columns in Foreign key.

So the general idea is, In table `SHIP_ROSTER`, column `Tweedle_No` alone is not unique and you can not reference any column which does not have unique values in it.

If your data structure allows then you can use unique constraint on `SHIP_ROSTER` table's `Tweedle_No` column, then your foreign constraint will work